# Minitest specs: multiple before/end blocks

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest

This a minimal generic example of the situation I have:

**test/mytest.rb**

```
describe "What I want to test" do
  include TestUtils

  temporary_change_value(settings, :tmp_setting, value)

  describe "test1 blablabla" do
    # ...
  end

  describe "test2 blablabla" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

**test/support/test_utils.rb**

```
module TestUtils

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      extend ClassMethods

      before do
        MyMainClass.interface = TestInterface.new
        MyMainClass.handler.display.clear
      end

      after do
        MyMainClass.handler.display.clear
      end
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def temporary_change_value(item, key, value)
      old_value = nil

      before do
        old_value = item[key]
        item[key] = value
      end

      after do
        item[key] = old_value
      end
    end

  end
end
```

The `TestUtils` module is included in evey test file so the common `before` and `end` tasks are always executed, but in this case I also need to use the method `temporary_change_value` as a before block for all the tests in this file. This is not working, it seems that only one of the `before`/`end` blocks gets executed (specifically the one that sets `MyMainClass.interface`)

*Things I've tried*

I've tried to change the order of the `before`/`end` blocks, like this.

```
describe "What I want to test" do
  extend TestUtils::ClassMethods

  temporary_change_value(settings, :tmp_setting, value)

  include TestUtils

  describe "test1 blablabla" do
    # ...
  end

  describe "test2 blablabla" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Still not working. Now the `settings` value doesn't get changed, so it seems that it is the second `before`/`end` block included the only one that gets executed.

The question: How can I achieve this and still keep it DRY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this thanks to the mantainer of the Minitest gem @zenspider.

**test/my_test.rb**

```
class TestWhatIWant < TestUtils::TestCase
  temporary_change_value settings, :tmp_setting, value

  describe "test1 blablabla" do
    # ...
  end

  describe "test2 blablabla" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

**test/support/test_utils.rb**

```
module TestUtils
  module ClassUtils

    def temporary_change_value item, key, value
      mod = Module.new do
        extend Minitest::Spec::DSL

        before do
          @old_value = item[key]
          item[key] = value
        end

        after do
          item[key] = @old_value
        end
      end

      include mod
    end

    class TestCase < Minitest::Spec
      extend TestUtils::ClassUtils
      include TestUtils

      def setup
        Byebug.interface = TestInterface.new
        Byebug.handler.display.clear
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: so the change is the setup block - what's the difference in how that functions from before/after?

Comment: Hi @dax, I don't remember the specifics of this situation but I can tell you that before/after implicitly call `super` whereas setup/teardown don't.

Comment: Hi deivid, thanks for your reply - actually I figured that bit about super out on my own after I saw this and ended up finding a more 'nuclear' option - before_setup.  it give precedence to itself (in the same way that setup does) but also calls super like a before block.  I think it's not a good option generally, as I can see it having some side effects - but it works as a temporary fix and exposed design flaws in current code, so I'll call it a success.

Answer (score 2):

Since MiniTest 3.3, before/end are just methods, not hooks, so when you call before do ... end, you are overwriting what used to be your before method.  What you can use instead is `MiniTest::TestCase.add_setup_hook` (http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Unit/TestCase.html#method-c-add_setup_hook).  You should be able to put the code from `temporary_change_value()` inside an `add_setup_hook` block in that particular test case to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That seems to be the problem indeed! I'll check this out soon and properly mark the question as solved after that. :)

Comment: Mmmm... It seems that add_setup_hook is has been dropped from Minitest, but you pointed me in the right direction... So I upvote you and leave the question open for now if that's ok with you.